# Do I need to re-write code to be asynchronous for all db operations?

Tags: asynchronous, redis, google-cloud-functions

I have this code running on my dev machine, along with a Redis instance.

```
if (req.url === "/get_id" && req.method === "GET") {
    console.log("Requesting an id");

    //Generate unique ID's until one is found and return it to the client
    let currentString = "";
    do {
      currentString = randomString({ length: 10 });
    } while (redisClient.SISMEMBER("uniqueSet", currentString) === 1);
    //the above will run until currentString is unique

    //add unique value to set
    redisClient.sadd("uniqueSet", currentString);
    console.log(currentString);

    //now return to client and close
    res.end(currentString);
  }
```

Will it work with cloud functions as is, or will I need to re-write it to be asynchronous? Also, would something like the above be a better fit for app-engine?

Comment: You won't have a local redis instance available on Cloud Functions, so that's not going to work at all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I saw this app engine example using localhost. https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex

Comment: The title on that page is "Connecting to a Redis instance from an App Engine Flexible Environment application". Cloud Functions is not an App Engine Flexible Environment application. The deployment description shows that it spins up a persistent engine on `env_variables: REDISHOST: '<redis-ip>' REDISPORT: '6379', which simply isn't possible on Cloud Functions, because your container may get shut down at any time between function invocations.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So actually you can connect to a Memorystore instance from Cloud Functions now ever since they allowed VPC connections between the two.  But anyway, what's working locally right now isn't going to work at all in Cloud Functions, and all network connections are going to be async in JavaScript anyway.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: Yea, I've been looking at all the documentation and it's kind of awesome all the options available, but I have a shoppers dilemma I guess, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up changing the code. When I launched and tested the cloud function it worked, so I'm going to assume it is fine... until I learn otherwise.

```
"use strict";

//const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const randomString = require("crypto-random-string");
const redis = require("redis");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST;
const REDISPORT = process.env.REDISPORT;

//use the unix socket option in production
const redisClient = redis.createClient(REDISPORT, REDISHOST); //unix_socket
const sismemberAsync = promisify(redisClient.sismember).bind(redisClient);

redisClient.on("error", function(err) {
  return;
  // but since this is an http function should I be calling res.end()?
});

//exports.my_id = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
exports.my_id = (req, res) => {
  async function getUnique() {
    try {
      //console.log("top function firing");
      let currentString = randomString({ length: 10 });
      let result = await sismemberAsync("uniqueSet", currentString);
      //console.log(result);

      // the element is unique
      if (result == 0) {
        //console.log("We are unique");
        redisClient.sadd("uniqueSet", currentString);
        res.end(currentString);
      }

      // the element is not unique
      if (result === 1) {
        //console.log("we are not unique");
        getUnique(); // try again
      }

      // the operation failed
      if (result === undefined) {
        //console.log("the async operation failed");
        getUnique(); // try again
        //res.end();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.end();
    }
  }

  // invoke the above function
  getUnique();
};
```

Things I'm still unsure on, in case anybody else might find it useful:

If a cloud function is an http invoked function does calling return end its execution or do you need to call res.end() or other res.function()? Mainly thinking about the redis on "error" function.

When I launched the function I used the console and set the environment variables from a drop down menu. I used the settings from my memorystore instance (including the host ip and port), but when setting up the serverless vpc access the connector I set up had a separate ip address. So, how the function found my Redis instance is beyond me, unless the connector just gets you to the vpc and then you can access any services running for the project in scope through there listed ip's?

I wonder if it's good to set up multiple connectors? Or a connector per function?

I heard it was a good idea to use unix sockets, because it allows for increased throughput or something, but I'm not sure if that is possible with the serverless solutions.